# Grails 2.3.8 console and dbconsole

Tags: grails

I was using the `grails console` to study GORM and I thought it would be pretty neat at the same time to run the application so that I could access the `dbconsole` via my browser at `localhost:8080/<nameOfApplication>/dbconsole`. This way I thought, I could see in `dbconsole`, the objects I was persisting using the `grails console`. However, in the `dbconsole`, I could not see the objects that I was persisting in the `grails console`. I tried the `dbconsole` in all environments (test, dev, prod) but it seems that the `grails console` doesn't operate so that I can see what it is doing in any of those environments. So my question is, did I do something wrong or is it the case the `grails console` persistence activity cannot be observed via the `dbconsole`?

Comment: are you using a in-memory h2 database? in this case, you will not be able to see the corresponding the database content. Can you show `DataSource.groovy`?

Comment: @MarioDavid Yes, I am. My DataSource.groovy is the default one that is created by the `create-app` command. I will switch to file based and see what happens.

Comment: @MarioDavid If I change the h2 database to file based instead of memory based, I can run either the `grails console` or my grails application. Trying to run one while the other is already running complains about db locked. My goal was to run them together alongside so I could study the effects of the `grails console` in the `dbconsole`. May be this isn't possible?

Comment: I would guess, you have forked mode enabled for Console, right? See BuildConfig.groovy. Turning it off should do the trick. Another alternative should be to use the [console plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/console), which is awesome and gives you additional benefits like auto Import of Domain classes. Check it out.

Comment: @MarioDavid Commenting out the console line from `grails.project.fork`, I still cannot run the console while the application is running. Still complains about a db lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [grails console plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/console) to run the application (in order to use /dbconsole) and side by side use the playground for console (visiting /console).

Go through the [summary section](https://github.com/sheehan/grails-console/blob/master/README.md) to know about its usage. This works the same way as `grails console` with some additional features like Local Storage.

Comment: Seems like exactly what I needed to deepen my understanding of GORM. Thanks.